Why is my Ender 3 nozzle z-axis raising before printing?
I just finished building my Ender 3 printer but the nozzle randomly goes up on the z-axis but won't go back down. Because of this, the filament isn't sticking to the bed and is just being dragged around whenever the nozzle moves.
P.S. I am using the memory card and test print included in the build.
Video of Problem: 



Hello. Have you checked for the behavior with a file you sliced yourself?
G-code files are (kind-of) human-readable files, lines that begin with "G1" or "G0" and that include a Z are adjusting the Z height, and may include a comment at the end of the line, after a " ; " character, that expounds on what the purpose of the move is.
Try a different G-code file and observe if this behavior happens with it, and open your G-code files and see if there's anything informative in the early lines that could explain what you see.

Have you correctly trammed the build plate?

This bed is not leveled correctly
It's clear from the video, that the bed is leveled far too low: the extrusion on the left side is supposed to happen at Z=0.3 mm over the bed, but it is clearly way higher.

I don't think that's it. You can see it home much lower, then raise something like a whole cm before starting the priming line. I think either the start gcode is wrong or there's some large Z offset saved in the firmware config.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE that too isn't leveled correctly to the nozzle. I explained how it is supposed to be leveled, not what is leading to the miss-leveling.

This actually might not be a printer problem. After the printer goes down, it clicks a little switch that tells it its position. it then goes up to make sure its not dragging on the bed. you can simply try raising the bed or if that doesnt work, buy another bed plate to put on top of the existing bed and adjust the height.
